# Facebook API - FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create') not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having spent hours trawling the web I have found many posts related to this but none seem to work, even some 'working' examples on jsfiddle appear not to work!

I want to register when a user clicks 'like' on my web page.

The 'like' link appears and indeed it pops up a new window for you to log into facebook.  But I cannot subscribe to the 'edge.create' event.  I know the sdk is loading ok because I can subscribe to the 'xfbml.render' event.

Some posts say that you must have an appId for this to work [I do] but others claim that it works without.

Here is my code:

One point to note is that I am currently running this under //localhost:57477, so I have set the like href to google.com.  I did note that one of the posts indentified a recent facebook bug where this event didn't fire if the href domain didn't match that of the web page, but this is now marked as 'fixed'.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>        
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        //console.log('window.fbAsyncInit');

        FB.init({
            appId: 'myappid', 
            status: false,
            cookie: false, 
            xfbml: true
        });

        //Additional initialization code here 
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                    function (response) {
                        //console.log('edge.create');
                        alert('edge.create');
                    }
             );

        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render',
                function (response) {
                    //console.log('xfbml.render');
                    alert('xfbml.render');
                }
             );
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>

<div href="http://google.com" class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best example I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509557/4681874

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread, but i came here with the same problem.
The thing that worked for me is that Facebook AppID must belong to a domain (set it in Facebook App settings) in which your site stands - localhost won't work then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me, I think the problem is in the FB.init() options.

This is what I use:

```
{
  appId: 'myappid',
  authResponse: false,
  channelUrl: "http://url-to-my-channel-url.com",
  cookie: true,
  oauth: true,
  status: true,
  xbfml: true
}
```

With these init options, I am able to use `edge.create` to track when someone clicks the Like button.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tried your settings in IE9/FFox/Chrome but still no edge.create event.  Everything works fine except the event subscription.

Comment: One point I'd like clarified: does the edge.create event fire when the user clicks the like button or only after they have logged into facebook in the popup?

Comment: I believe it fires after an actual Like has taken place, so login is required.

Comment: Progress of sorts....Its works in IE9 albeit with this script error: Object doesn't support property or method '__gcb2' AND the edge.create doesn't work at all in FFox or chrome and the javascript console is full of errors: 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL'